# Exclude some URLs from the session timeout

Tags: jsp, session-timeout, weblogic12c

I have a web app with a 30 min session timeout. The design is that when the session is dropped the user is automatically logged out and needs to sign in again.

Problem is that I have a news ticker on my web page that updates every 5 minutes via an AJAX call. The newsticker AJAX call naturally resets the session timeout, so the users don't get logged out.

I was thinking of implementing my own inactivity detector by writing a filter that updates a `lastActive` variable (stored in the session) whenever the user gets/posts a page, except for the news ticker.

Then I was thinking, maybe there is a way to exclude certain calls from resetting the session timeout. So I searched and found some answers relating to asp, but nothing for jsp and Weblogic.

Is there a way to exclude certain URL:s from resetting the session timeout?

Comment: Can't you put the ticker in a separate WAR file, which has its own web.xml which will have its own timeout?

Comment: @radimpe I could, but when I add up what I need to do it seems like more work and a more complex solution than writing a filter. The application currently has just one web app. I'm also not sure how to handle things like authorization and authentication  transparantly with a second web app that uses separate sessions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I couldn't find any way to do this by configuration I ended up writing a filter that invalidates the session when enough time has passed without user activity. I already had another filter in place that redirects users without a session to the login page. I added the `SessionTimeoutFilter` just before the authorisation filter in the filter chain.

The code below is slightly stripped. I have removed all internal dependencies, that is why all values are hardcoded.

```
public class SessionTimeoutFilter
    implements Filter
{
    private final long TIMEOUT = 1800L; // 30 minutes in seconds
    private final String LAST_ACTIVITY = "LAST_ACTIVITY";

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

        if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
            HttpServletRequest theRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
            Long now = (new Date()).getTime();

            HttpSession session = theRequest.getSession(false);
            if (session != null) {
                Long lastActivity = (Long) session.getAttribute(LAST_ACTIVITY);

                if (lastActivity == null) {
                    // The first call for this session.
                    lastActivity = now;
                }
                if (now - lastActivity > TIMEOUT*1000L) {
                    // User timed out.
                    session.invalidate();
                } else if (isUserCall(theRequest)) {
                    // Reset inactivity timer
                    session.setAttribute(LAST_ACTIVITY, now);
                }
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    /** 
     * @return true  if the URI indicates user activity, 
     *         false if it is an automatic call
     */
    private boolean isUserCall(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String uri = request.getRequestURI();
        if (uri.contains("NewsTicker")) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Klas Lindback : I don't have enough privilege to comment.So i'm posting this as answer.To find last activity, you don't need to the manual calculation.Try the following method

```
session.getLastAccessedTime()
```

[Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html)

Anyhow that won't change your implementation

Comment: `session.getLastAccessedTime()` doesn't do it for me, since it gets reset by any call, including the newsticker Ajax calls that I want to exclude from the timeout calculation.

Comment: what it is resetting?